# How do I get a variable value that is stored in a string in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a file with strings that include variables. I want to retrieve the string with the value of the variable being represented in the string. I have tried `${!var}` without success.

A file called test.line with the string and a variable:

```
$ cat test.line 
Hello $var3
```

A bash script called test.sh:

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

var1="hello"
var2="goodbye"
var3="again"

## works
str="$var1 and $var2"
echo $str

## does not work--prints $var3 instead of "again"
str="$(cat test.line)"
echo $str
```

Output of test.sh when run:

```
$ ./test.sh 
hello and goodbye
Hello $var3
```

Desired output of test.sh when run:

```
$ ./test.sh 
hello and goodbye
Hello again
```

Comment: This will help you: [http://mywiki.wooledge.org/TemplateFiles](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/TemplateFiles).

Comment: PesaThe... I am trying to wrap my head around this TemplateFiles page you suggested.  Cyrus' solution is a quick and easy for now, but I appreciate the link.

Comment: Problem is that using `eval` is potentially dangerous. If the file is not under your control, I would suggest other alternatives. Someone could inject code like this in your file `blabla $(rm -rf *)` and it would get executed.

Comment: I was concerned about that, but I don't have another solution. Fortunately, this is a script for my personal use on my own computer.  Any pointers in how to implement a safer alternative?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

var1="hello"
var2="goodbye"
var3="again"

## works
str="$var1 and $var2"
echo $str

## SOLVED -- Does work
str="$(cat test.line)"
eval echo $str   # This is the line that SOLVED it
```

Output of test.sh when run:

```
$ ./test.sh 
hello and goodbye
Hello again ##This is what I want (SOLVED)
```